# Convert an Appscript instance to run in Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I've used Google's standard example for attaching files from a Google Drive folder to a Site, found here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/embedding_docslist_in_sites#section1

```
function showFolderInSiteCab() {
  var files = DocsList.getFolderById('FOLDER ID GOES HERE').getFiles();
  var page = SitesApp.getPageByUrl('URL GOES HERE');
  var fileAsPdf;
  var attachments = page.getAttachments();

  for (i in attachments) {
    attachments[i].deleteAttachment();
  }

  for (i in files) {
    fileAsPdf = files[i];
   page.addHostedAttachment(fileAsPdf);
  }
}
```

However, when trying to attach the files to the site, the script times out.
Is there a way to use/convert that script to work within Appengine so the process can run each time, without needing to worry about the 6 minute limit?

Comment: um, yes, learn python/php/java/go and re-implement in GAE?

Comment: App Engine is a different beast, and Apps Script is not "portable" like that. You'll have to learn lots of other stuff and like Paul said, re-implement it in GAE.

Answer (score 3):

Not possible. Read more about gae to understand the difference.
For starters, in appengine you will have only 30seconds instead of 6minutes to run it, unless you use taskqueues or modules.